# Page not updating in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a test project web site using angular (learning) and ng-view does not update when I click on Test on index.html page. I have been looking for last 2 hours on web and tried several solutions and nothing worked. Please help in what I am doing wrong!!!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Angular References -->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jcs-auto-validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- CSLMS App Angular References -->
    <script src="CSLMS_app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="CSLMS_app/Recipe_Values/ConstantValues.js"></script>
    <script src="CSLMS_app/Controllers/indexController.js"></script>
    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="CSLMS_app">
    <div ng-controller="indexController">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top" >
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CS-LMS</a>
                </div>  <!-- /.navbar-header -->
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#/Test">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{user.username}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;">Links</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;">Edit Profile</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.html

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <h1>test Pagerr</h1>
    <br />
    {{message}}

    <script src="../CSLMS_app/Controllers/testController.js"></script>
</div>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

//var app = angular.module('CSLMS_app', ['jcs-autoValidate', 'ngRoute']);
var app= angular.module('CSLMS_app', ['jcs-autoValidate', 'ngRoute']);


app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/Login", {
        templateUrl: "Pages/Login.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    })
    .when("/Test", {
        templateUrl: "Pages/Test.html",
        controller: "testController"
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Test' })
}]);
```

testController.js

```
'use strict';
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {
    $scope.message = "Test ";
}])
```

indexController.js

```
'use strict';
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.somedata = "That";
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: You can use $location.replace('/test')

Comment: Please check if you have any error in console, however have you tried to remove the script source from Test.html and put it in the index.html page?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery with AngularJS, reference it before AngularJS. Also, generally you want to include your scripts just before the end of the body element.

Comment: issue not fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but you might want to move this:

```
<script src="../CSLMS_app/Controllers/testController.js"></script>
```

out of Test.html and into the `<head>` element of index.html. I suspect that is one issue. There may be more, but I would at least do that.

Comment: Did that and no difference

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load your script for testController. Add this line to your index.html:

```
<script src="CSLMS_app/Controllers/testController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Mistalis  - The above script was loaded in my Test.html file but removed it from there and moved it to the index.html file. Still no difference and have no error in console. Any ideas!!!

Comment: Would this be an issue - I am running VS2015 and IIS Express. I read the ng-route needs a web server - ?